# Can I avoid `DateTime::__construct` warning on invalid date?

Tags: php, datetime

This is about `DateTime::__construct`. According to this [comment](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php#116480):

> If time cannot be parsed an exception of type Exception is thrown which can be caught, however an E_WARNING is emitted as well. This might be confusing if you are converting warnings to exceptions in your error or shutdown handler.

Can I avoid the warning? I have a code like (I don't care if the date is well formed or not):

```
try {
    $var = new DateTime('some invalid date format');
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    $var = null;
}
```

But it still send a E_WARNING that is reported to my error catcher (I use NewRelic in a Laravel application). And I don't want this error to be reported because it's not an error, I catched it.

**How can I avoid `DateTime::__construct` emit a warning?**

Comment: I don't think the `DateTime` class is designed with an option for you to make it avoid throwing an exception or emitting a warning. *This is how it is made*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possibly one of the few cases where it's acceptable to use:

```
try {
    $var = @new DateTime('some invalid date format');         
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $var = null;
}
```

However you can avoid the `@` operator by doing:

```
try {
    $oldErrorReporting = error_reporting();
    error_reporting($oldErrorReporting & ~E_WARNING);
    $var = new DateTime('some invalid date format'); 
    error_reporting($oldErrorReporting);        
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $var = null;
}
```

Comment: I try to avoid `@`like the plague, I have really bad memories about it years ago! Anyway, thanks +1! I choose the second option!

Comment: @rap-2-h by the way I think it's also possible to just catch a `Throwable` if you're using PHP 7 + and avoid this issue completely.

Comment: wow! It seems better (cleaner I mean)! Could you edit your answer and add this? (I'm using php7.0)

Comment: I'm pretty sure warnings are unchanged in PHP 7 - it's only errors that are converted to `Error` throwables

Comment: Actually @iainn is correct. I still get the warning in `error_get_last` when I catch a throwable. I was just unsure because it seems laravel doesn't terminate execution in that case. (the warning would still go to NewRelic probably)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`date_create()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php) function instead.

It (I assume) internally works similar to the `try/catch` block you want to avoid and returns `FALSE` if the date is not valid. It doesn't trigger any error or warning.

The code:

```
$var = date_create('some invalid date format');
```

is, more or less, the same as:

```
try {
    $var = new DateTime('some invalid date format');
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    $var = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create an error handler like this:

```
//set_error_handler();
set_error_handler(function($msg, $code, $severity, $file, $lineno, $errText) {
    if (0 === error_reporting()) {
        return false;
    }
    throw new ErrorException($msg, $code, $severity, $file, $lineno);
});
```

Then,

```
try {
    $var = new DateTime('some invalid date format');
} catch (ErrorException $exception) {
    $var = null;
}
```